# Transfer of oracle dump file through mail which allows only 5mb max upload

Tags: oracle, dump, transfer

i want to transfer my oracle database dump file from one place to another, and size of database is 80mb even if i 7 zip it coverts to 9mb. but mail allows me to upload maximum of 5mb data, so can i break my dump file? and at the same time i dont want to loose the key structure in database.
P.S. all the other mails are blocked and cloud spaces are also bloacked.

Comment: And network sharing is not an option?

Comment: upload to cloud storage instead?

Comment: all cloud storage are blocked. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet the constraints of your network, you can create dump files of smaller size, which will enable you to create dump files of 5 MB (or smaller than that).

```
exp user/pass FILE=D:P1.dmp,E:P2.dmp FILESIZE=5m LOG=splitdump.log
```

I have not tried the above syntax, but have tried this one, where a substitution variable is used, ensuring that you need not worry about how many dump files you have to specify beforehand. This will automatically generate as many dump files, as needed of requisite size

```
expdp user/pass tables=test directory=dp_dir dumpfile=dump%u.dmp filesize=5m
```

Comment: thank you so much i will implement it and hopefully thank you once again after this scripts success ;p